# Configure 2 sites in the IIS of windows Server 2016

Tags: asp.net, iis, dns

I have to configure a staging site of my web application in Windows Server 2016.

I have ASP.net site which is running smoothly in my win server 2016, and I have configured A record from my bluehost DNS Manager.

**My Question:** I want to add a new site in the IIS of my server using same port. So how I could manage to reach it from A record or CNAME record from bluehost?

Comment: https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html#background Just learn and set the right site bindings.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, IIS doesn’t allow two websites to use the same port number when we using the same alias for the local machine.
To create a unique binding, we need to specify another name(HostName) for the second website. Edit the binding and specify the unique hostname the user will address to.
[image]
Now, we can start the second website as well.
[image]
All we have to do is to add an alias for the server(A or CNAME) to DNS that specifies the IP address or the name of your web server.
[image]
Here is a related discussion.
http://woshub.com/run-multiple-websites-on-the-same-port-and-ip-address-on-iis/
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.

Comment: Hello, I asked the similar question on [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/1029719/do-i-have-to-set-web-farm-for-multiple-web-sites-in-the-same-iis-server), do you think that answer is right?

Comment: @Bigeyes ,  In my opinion, web farm typically is used to handle high load sites or improve the web service high availability. therefore the web farm typically consists of multiple IIS servers. Hosting multiple websites on a single IIS server is fine. It is unnecessary to use web farm when the website load isn't high, especially, there is only one web server is used to work.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Forget the web farm issue. My question actually is that http and https use the same port number when we using the same alias for the local machine. Is that okay?Further my question contains 4 web sites, they use the same alias. I am not sure is that okay?

Comment: As far as I know, it is impossible to use the same port number over HTTP and https when we use the same alias for the IIS web server. Due to the fact that we can not identify the website by using the same URL, otherwise, you can add the new website as a sub-application to the same website.