# IIS Redirect HTTP to HTTPS for same domain names on the same IIS

Tags: angular, redirect, .net-core, https, iis-8.5

I have a special case:
There are sites on the same IIS:

1. sub.domain.com - it has http on 80 and https on 443. It works just great with your redirection way from http to https

   ```
        <configuration>
            <system.webServer>
                <rewrite>
                    <rules>
                        <rule name="HTTPS force" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                            <match url="(.*)" />
                            <conditions>
                               <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
                            </conditions>
                            <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" 
               redirectType="Permanent" />
                      </rule>
                  </rules>
               </rewrite>
            </system.webServer>
     </configuration>
   ```
2. http://sub.domain.com:5000 and https//sub.domain.com:5001. That one just refuses to pass from http to https to the right port. It can direct from http://sub.domain.com:5000 to https://sub.domain.com:5000 instead of https://sub.domain.com:5001. Unless we clear the browsing data then it only works one time from  http://sub.domain.com:5000 to https://sub.domain.com:5001. The rule likes

   ```
        <rule name="HTTP to HTTPS on different SSL Port" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
       <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="true" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="true">
              <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
              <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="([^/:]*?):[^/]*?" />
          </conditions>
       <action type="Redirect" url="https://{C:1}:5001/{R:0}" appendQueryString="false" />
    </rule>
   ```

So my question is that how can I redirect http://sub.domain.com:5000 to https://sub.domain.com:5001 successfully without clearing browsing data etc?

**UPDATE:**

After I log the failed requested log, I found something.
I have 18 files in `FailedReqLogFiles\W3SVC4`. Each of them has a different requestURL.

1. The first one is `http://somedomain.com:5000/`, status code 301;
2. The second one is `https://somedomain.com:5001/`, status code 200.
3. The third one is `https://somedomain.com:5001/inline.e576fger98965b3219.bundle.js`, status code 200.
4. The fourth one is `https://somedomain.com:5001/polyfills.3bed24531fd9085545fdw.bundle.js`, status code 200.
5. Etc.....
6. The last one(18th) is `https://somedomain.com:5001/assets/images/action,jpg`.

If I look at the GENERAL_ENDPOINT_INFORMATION nodes in Request Detail Tab.It shows `Failed To Complete` in every log file.

****IMPORTANT:****

This is .net core plus angular application. I am not sure should I configure ssl and redirect https in angular side rather than IIS or both sides?

Comment: Do you have `Strict-Transport-Security` http response headers? It yes, then it can explain why it works one time after cache clearing. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security

Comment: @StanislavBerkov, I do have it. `Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=2592000`

Comment: But in angular code http header setting, I don't have this.Should I add it in Angular?

Comment: I am saying that Strict-Transport-Security can be root cause of the problem. Try removing it.

Comment: @StanislavBerkov, I am not sure how to remove it. In IIS, I don't add it in response headers. The response headers only contains `X-Powered-By: ASP.NET`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several days struggle. Finally I find the solution.

I have to do two things.

1. Apply rules on IIS

   ```
   <rule name="HTTP to HTTPS on different SSL Port" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
   <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="true" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="true">
          <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
          <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="([^/:]*?):[^/]*?" />
      </conditions>
   <action type="Redirect" url="https://{C:1}:5001/{R:0}" appendQueryString="false" />
   ```
2. Remove HSTS from .net core code. I had the code

   ```
       public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
       {
          app.UseHsts();
   ```

Remove it then works. Thank @StanislavBerkov

Answer (score 1):

You could try below rule:

```
 <rule name="HTTP to HTTPS on different SSL Port" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="true" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="true">
                    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
                    <add input="{SERVER_PORT}" pattern="^2000$" />
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="([^/:]*?):[^/]*?" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://{C:1}:2001/{R:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
            </rule>
```

Note: set port number in a pattern based on your site binding and requirement.

[image]

also, try to set the iis client cache setting.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/staticcontent/clientcache

Comment: I think that your rules only work on the case which only has an unique domain name on IIS. If you have another site which has the same, perhaps it doesn't work. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61890199/configure-2-sites-in-the-iis-of-windows-server-2016/61907364?noredirect=1#comment112189151_61907364. The comments in that answer maybe useful. Please verify it. Thanks.

Comment: And I added the failed request tracking. I only got `REWRITE_DISABLED_KERNEL_CACHE` warning. Not sure whether it is related.

Comment: @Bigeyes could you share the failed request trace log as shown in this image. [image](https://i.imgur.com/RONisPp.png). the domain name for the same site for HTTP and https is ok. but the port number should be different.  and if possible use the default port for https 443 is recommended.

Comment: @Bigeyes could you share more detail what you mean by "If you have another site which has the same, perhaps it doesn't work. " are you using the same domain name for different sites?

Comment: I mean if you have `http://www.somedomain.com:80` and `https://www.somedomain.com:443`, it is okay for redirect http to https. But in my case on the same IIS. I am developing new site with the same domain name withe the different ports to differentiate the existing sites. So I have the sites which are `http://www.somedomain.com:5000` and `https://www.somedomain.com:5001`. In another word, I have the same domain name for different sites. The redirect is not working for the developing sites but it works for the existing sites. Unless we clear the browsing data every time.

Comment: In other words, I have 4 sites `http://www.somedomain.com:80`;`https://www.somedomain.com:443`;`http://www.somedomain.com:5000` and `https://www.somedomain.com:5001`. The first two sites can be redirected, the lat two sites can't be directed unless we clear the browsing data every time.

Comment: i make a test at my site as you explain at my site both the site is working properly without clearing browser history. please check the [image](https://i.imgur.com/LZCaJFJ.gif)

Comment: I update the info, please check it. It is an asp.net core and angular application.

Comment: @Bigeyes in which browser you are getting this issue? did you try other browsers?

Comment: I tried in Microsoft Edge and Chrome. Same thing....

Comment: Do I need to install ARR module?

Comment: @Bigeyes no need to install the arr for the URL rewrite rule. it is not mandatory. could you please check the frt for  http://somedomain.com:5000/ this url. does RULE_EVALUATION_END  Succeeded is true or false?

Comment: If I clear the cache first then the FailedReqLog is not created at all. It can be redirected. Otherwise it failed also still no log. My log in the post maybe something else when I modified the web.config. It seems not related. Sorry for confusion.